# Heroku build fails on uglifier

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, gemfile

My minimal app runs locally and I have no bundle errors. When I push to heroku, however, the build fails during assets:precompile step:

```
...
Bundle completed (3.24s)
Cleaning up the bundler cache.
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
Running: rake assets:precompole
rake aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- uglifier
(in /tmp/build_.../app/assets/javascripts/application.js)
```

**Notes:**
**1.** I am not using the uglifier gem locally
**2.** I do not have a file app/assets/javascripts/application.js

I have tried these Gemfile solutions:
**A)** adding the uglifier gem
**B)** adding uglifier to the assets group
**C)** removing uglifier completely from Gemfile and rake uninstall all versions

What's next?

Comment: You don't want to use the asset pipeline at all?

Comment: check if you have javascript error on the browser console. Try precompile on local machine.

Comment: The precompile locally works except for pg_ext, which seems to be a different issue than uglifier. What I don't understand is why uglifier is being referenced at all since I removed it from the Gemfile and uninstalled all versions??

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Comment this line in config/environments/production.rb

```
config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
```

Comment: Do not forget to commit before the next push! :-)

Answer (score 19):

A better solution, if you want to compress your assets, is to add `uglifier` to your GEMFILE:

`gem 'uglifier'`

Answer (score 6):

If you're interested in continuing to use `uglifier`, you can add it to your `Gemfile` (and install with Bundler) -- as explained by @mindtonic.

Also, if you're using ES6, you'll need to switch:

```
config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
```

to:

```
config.assets.js_compressor = Uglifier.new(harmony: true)
```

As explained in https://github.com/lautis/uglifier/issues/127

Answer (score 1):

You have to focus on two points:

**Point 1.** Version of the Gem: This should be **4.2**

```
gem 'uglifier', '~> 4.2'
```

**Point 2.** Use js compressor now

```
config.assets.js_compressor = Uglifier.new(harmony: true)
```

Comment: The version bump was the important part for me. Thanks